# Subprocess in Python: File Name too long

Tags: python, shell

I try to call a shellscript via the subprocess module in Python 2.6.

```
import subprocess

shellFile = open("linksNetCdf.txt", "r")

for row in shellFile:
    subprocess.call([str(row)])
```

My filenames have a length ranging between 400 and 430 characters.
When calling the script I get the error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 444, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

An example of the lines within `linksNetCdf.txt` is

```
./ShellScript 'Title' 'Sometehing else' 'InfoInfo' 'MoreInformation' inputfiile outputfile.txt 3 2
```

Any ideas how to still run the script?

Comment: Have u tried to figure out what the maximum allowed length for a filename is set to on your system `getconf NAME_MAX /`

Comment: Might display a `head` of linksNetCdf.txt

Comment: @flazzarini it works when I type it "manually" or copying the link from the .txt. and paste it into the ssh secure client...

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. no there is no head in the .txt, just the ./..sh ... commands

Comment: @Stoffer: no, he means run the command `head linksNetCdf.txt`, and show us the results...

Comment: @Stoffer I mean the command `head` .... in other words, show the first  lines of the file

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Ehm that is problematic cause the data in there is kind of sensitive... What are you interested, I can extract it

Comment: Then edit out the sensitive data by replacing it e.g. with PASSWORD instead of the real thing. But unless we see the actual commands, we can't possibly judge what's going on.

Comment: @Stoffer How does the ShellScript look like? Does it have a shebang?

Comment: @deets I never work with ShellScript. I got this to reformat some data. I prepare the datainput with python in the format which is needed. That works fine cause I can call the shell script "by hand". So, what is shebang?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`subprocess.call` can take the command to run in two ways - either a single string like you'd type into a shell, or a list of the executable name followed by the arguments.

You want the first, but were using the second

```
import subprocess

shellFile = open("linksNetCdf.txt", "r")

for row in shellFile:
    subprocess.call(row, shell=True)
```

By converting your `row` into a list containing a single string, you're saying something like *"Run the command named `echo these were supposed to be arguments` with no arguments"*

Comment: There are parameters in my command I want to run. Jose Ricardo Bustos M. mentioned that that might be problematic.

Comment: This supports having parameters just fine. You could try using `subprocess.call(row, shell=True)`

Answer (score 13):

You need to tell subprocess to execute the line as full command including arguments, not just one program.

This is done by passing shell=True to call

```
 import subprocess
 cmd = "ls " + "/tmp/ " * 30
 subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```