# File name too long error when building HTML files

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm attempting to build HTML documentation on Ubuntu 18.04 but I'm running into a strange error when I run `make html`:

```
Exception occurred:


File "/home/cybo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbsphinx.py", line 917, in parse
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '/home/cybo/Desktop/repositories/h2oai/docs/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/_build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx__build_doctrees_nbsphinx_examples_autoviz_client_example_autoviz_client_example_11_1.png'
```

I'm able to fix the error by deleting these folders, but they are created again:

```
reading sources... [ 44%] _build/html/_build/html/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/_build/html/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/_build/doctrees/nbsphinx/examples/autoviz_client_example/autoviz_c
```

Would appreciate any help, seems to be some sort of circular referencing error that I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: Since you are using Ubuntu, [this thread might explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503540/why-does-python-give-oserror-errno-36-file-name-too-long-for-filename-short). The second answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747108/subprocess-in-python-file-name-too-long) might solve your problem if you include it in your `docs/conf.py` file. [Have your tried these threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=OSError%3a%20Errno%2036%20File%20name%20too%20long%3a). You haven't explained you project structure, or the steps you took before `make html`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error using `nbsphinx`. The problem was that I had neglected to set `exclude_patterns` in my `conf.py` and each successive build was creating an HTML file for everything in `_build`. This meant that each build was exponentially slower than the previous one. What a nightmare!

I fixed it by putting the following in my `conf.py`:

```
extensions = [
    'nbsphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
]
exclude_patterns = ['_build', '**.ipynb_checkpoints']
```

I found this information originally in the [nbsphinx instructions](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/usage.html). Hope it helps!